# How to execute query to select multiple attributes subject to several where clauses across two tables

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have two tables from which I want to select data from:

```
Document_Data
Document_info
```

I want to execute the following query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT Document_Data.DOC_CLASS, TITLE FROM Document_info,Document_Data WHERE (((DOC_STATUS = '1') AND (PORTAL = 'First Page'))) AND (Document_info.DOC_NUMBER = Document_Data.DOC_NUMBER AND Document_info.REVISION = Document_Data.REVISION AND STATUS = 'CURRENT' AND Document_Data.DOC_CLASS = 'MESSAGE')
```

Can anyone give me info on how to execute the following query using Linq?

Comment: On which table does STATUS appear (or does it appear on both)? Your query says STATUS="1" and STATUS="CURRENT" which seems contradictory...

Comment: Apologies, I made an error when writing my query, I updated it

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What problem(s) are you having with your own attempt at translating this query?  Which operations are you capable of translating properly and which do you not understand how to map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a few assumptions since your query did leave off a few table names. I assumed that STATUS was on the Document_data table and DOC_STATUS was on the Document_info table. If its any different, it shouldn't be hard to modify this query to work.

DbContext is your entity framework context or wherever your store your db collections.

```
dbContext.Document_info.Where(i => i.DOC_STATUS == "1" && i.PORTAL == "First Page")
    .Join(dbContext.Document_data.Where(d => d.DOC_CLASS == "MESSAGE" && d.STATUS == "CURRENT"),
        i => new { i.REVISION, i.DOC_NUMBER }, //Document_info
        d => new { d.REVISION, d.DOC_NUMBER }, //Document_data
        (i, d) => new { d.DOC_CLASS, i.TITLE }) //(Document_info, Document_data)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

The way this works is that it first filters the document_info table to what you wanted from there. It then joins it with a filtered Document_data table on a composite "key" made up of `REVISION` and `DOC_NUMBER`. After that, it runs the Distinct and executes the whole query with a `ToList`.

The above should compile to valid SQL (at least it would using the MySQL connector...I haven't tried anything like that with MSSQL, but I assume that since the MSSQL one works better than MySQL so it would make sense that it would work there too). This particular query would come out to be a little convoluted, however, and might not work very optimally unless you have some foreign keys defined on `REVISION` and `DOC_NUMBER`.

I would note that your query will only return things where `d.DOC_CLASS == "MESSAGE"` and so your results will be quite repetitious.

Comment: Hi - thanks for your reply, looks like my attempt except I'm getting an error on : ""1" && i.PORTAL == "Meeting Page"" of "operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'bool'"

Comment: Whoops. Typo on my part. That `=` should be a `==`. Fixed.